# Кэш страниц, Python

Tags: python, django

Как сделать так, чтобы страницы отданные питон-движком, джанго, не кэшились на клиентской стороне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как же так? Не может такого быть, чтобы было нельзя. Это не настройки браузера. Когда вы отдаёте страницы, то вы указываете в HTTP-заголовках expiration date и можете указать режим кэширования. Стало быть, вы должны выставить дату заведомо прошедшую и выбрать режим режим кэширования, при котором кэширования нет:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно отправить браузеру соответствующие заголовки (как, опередив меня, правильно указал cy6erGn0m).

Странно, мне казалось, Джанго по-умолчанию отключает кэширование (конечно, если Вы не используете в своём приложении cache framework).

Чтобы явно отключить кэширования для данного view (это как раз и нужно, если включен cache framework, который по-дефолту что-то кэширует), надо использовать декоратор `django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache`.

---

Если не связываться с cache framework, то можно просто выставить заголовок `Cache-Control: no-cache`. Делается это примерно так:

```
>>> response = HttpResponse()
>>> response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
```